# How to specify AND and OR search between keywords in Azure Search SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am developing an Azure Function that makes a call to an Azure Search, gets the search results based on some keywords and then sends it back to the front end application.
I have a searchable column in my Azure Search Data Source (an Azure Table). It contains comma separated string with keywords like

- Digital, Technology, 3D
- Digital, Technology, AR
- Digital, Manufacturing, Chemicals
- Digital, Manufacturing, Medicines

Now I wish to do a search as follows :

- (Digital, Technology, 3D) OR (Digital, Manufacturing,
  Chemicals)

which should fetch me all record with column value as

- Digital, Technology, 3D
- Digital, Manufacturing, Chemicals

I am not able to implement this. I am aware of the SearchMode.Any and SearchMode.All but I am not able to find out how can I implement the OR between the above 2 groups.

Comment: Is the index field containing this data `filterable`?

Comment: Do you really need full-text search in this case, or are you looking for exact matches for each group?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes. It is filterable.

Comment: @BruceJohnston Exact matches for each group. While inserting the data, we have made sure that each group will be an exact match with the incoming search request. For eg. Search Request can be 
(Digital, Technology) or (Digital) or (Digital, Technology, 3D)

Comment: You can try using a filter query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search.

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to query for exact matches, you should use an OData filter instead of a search query. You can do this using the .NET SDK like this (assuming your filterable field name is called 'Categories'):

```
string filter = "Categories eq 'Digital, Technology, 3D' or Categories eq 'Digital, Manufacturing, Chemicals'";
var params = new SearchParameters() { Filter = filter };
var result = indexClient.Documents.Search("*", params);
```